# Setting value to info.plist file from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, info.plist

I want to change/modify some value in `info.plist` from Swift programmatically. For example I want to change "`NSAllowsArbitaryLoads`" to 0.
This is code what I am using for editing the value:

```
func editPlist(){
    var infoPlistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist")

    var infoPlistDict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: playersDictionaryPath!)

    var nsAppKey = infoPlistDict?.object(forKey: "NSAppTransportSecurity") as! NSDictionary

    print(nsAppKey["NSAllowsArbitraryLoads"])
    nsAppKey["NSAllowsArbitraryLoads"] = 0
}
```

In reality I want to change my exported UTIs image in Swift programmatically. I want to change it for each object that I want to share via `UIActivityController`.

P.S. : I am using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.

Comment: The Info.plist is – like all files in the application bundle – *read only.* You cannot modify it at runtime.

Comment: You can't modify a file inside your bundle. You have to make a copy to it and write it elsewhere. In our case, you won't be able to modify Info.plist at runtime.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. But how can I change my exported UTIs image from Swift? I think It's just accessible from Info.plist file. So I need to modify it and because of it I ask the question. So is there anyway to change exported UTIs image dynamically?

Comment: @Larme Thank you. Is there anyway to change exported UTIs image dynamically?

Comment: I am fairly sure that you can't. Also confirmed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116552/adding-exported-type-utis-programmatically-for-in-app-purchase.

Comment: @MartinR Aha thank you. So I can just use a static image for that.